# unresolved external symbol, stack being implemented by vector

Tags: c++, vector, stack

I have been working on this project for a while now and have tried multiple things.  Please help me, I always get new errors, this is the latest one.

```
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class miniStackVT<int> __cdecl myStack(void)" (?myStack@@YA?AV?$miniStackVT@H@@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl stackVector(void)" (?stackVector@@YAXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall miniStackVT<int>::~miniStackVT<int>(void)" (??1?$miniStackVT@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl stackVector(void)" (?stackVector@@YAXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall miniStackVT<int>::size(void)const " (?size@?$miniStackVT@H@@QBEHXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl stackVector(void)" (?stackVector@@YAXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall miniStackVT<int>::Push(int const &)" (?Push@?$miniStackVT@H@@QAEXABH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl stackVector(void)" (?stackVector@@YAXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall miniStackVT<int>::PrintStack(void)const " (?PrintStack@?$miniStackVT@H@@QBEXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl stackVector(void)" (?stackVector@@YAXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall miniStackVT<int>::Pop(void)" (?Pop@?$miniStackVT@H@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl stackVector(void)" (?stackVector@@YAXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall miniStackVT<int>::TopStack(void)const " (?TopStack@?$miniStackVT@H@@QBEHXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl stackVector(void)" (?stackVector@@YAXXZ)
```

Here is my main file main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "miniStack.h"
//#include "miniQueue.h"

using namespace std;
void Menu();
void stackVector();

int main()
{
Menu();
return 0;
}

void Menu()
{
int num = 0;
do{
    cout << "Will you be using: " << endl;
    cout << "1 Stack" << endl;
    cout << "2 Queue" << endl;
    cin >> num;
} while (num != 1 && num != 2);
if (num == 1)
{
    do {
        cout << "Will you be using: " << endl;
        cout << "1 vector" << endl;
        cout << "2 list" << endl;
        cout << "3 dynamic array" << endl;
        cin >> num;
    } while (num != 1 && num != 2 && num != 3);
    if (num == 1) // Stack vector
    {
        stackVector();
    }
    else if (num == 2) // Stack list
    {
        //stackList();
    }
    else if (num == 3) // Stack dynamic array
    {
        //stackArray();
    }
}
else if (num == 2)
{
    do{
        cout << "Will you be using: " << endl;
        cout << "1 vector" << endl;
        cout << "2 list" << endl;
        cout << "3 dynamic array" << endl;
        cin >> num;
    } while (num != 1 && num != 2 && num != 3);
    if (num == 1) // Queue vector
    {
        //queueVector();
    }
    else if (num == 2) // Queue list
    {
        //queueList();
    }
    else if (num == 3) // Queue dynamic array
    {
        //queueArray();
    }
}
}

void stackVector()
{
int num;
int item;
miniStackVT<int> myStack();
cout << "Please choose from the following menu: " << endl;
cout << "1 Add an element" << endl;
cout << "2 Remove an element" << endl;
cout << "3 display the contents" << endl;
cout << "4 display the size" << endl;
cout << "5 display the first element" << endl;
cin >> num;
if (num == 1)
{
    cout << "What you like to add into the stack?" << endl;
    cin >> item;
    myStack().Push(item);
}
else if (num == 2)
{
    myStack().Pop();
}
else if (num == 3)
{
    myStack().PrintStack();
}
else if (num == 4)
{
    cout << myStack().size();
}
else if (num == 5)
{
    cout << myStack().TopStack();
}
}
```

Comment: Sarah I suggest you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead.

Comment: That is what this is, my real program is much larger.

Comment: @Try to provide chunks of code only. People here do not like to go through that amount of code.

Comment: I edited the code, how is that? is that too much still?

Comment: That is all that is needed. The problem is a duplicate. Templates can not be implemented in a cpp file.

Comment: Still getting the same error when I implement the templates in a header file.

Comment: `miniStackVT<int> myStack();` Should be `miniStackVT<int> myStack;` Replace all `myStack().` with `myStack`